# Throwing Java exception in JRuby and catching it in Java

Tags: java, exception, jruby, throw, raise

I have created my own UI component in Java. It has model and a few of model's methods can throw my exception called ModelException. I want to use this component in JRuby but I can't raise my ModelException:

```
raise ModelException # it cause TypeError: exception class/object expected
```

So I tried to create method throwing ModelException in Java and then invoke it in JRuby:

```
public class ScriptUtils {

private ScriptUtils() {
}

public static void throwModelException(ModelException e)
        throws ModelException {
    throw e;
}
}
```

but when I call throwModelException from JRuby I get:

```
org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: Native Exception: 'class  app.ui.ModelException';   Message:
; StackTrace: app.ui.ModelException
...
Caused by: app.ui.ModelException
```

this native exception cannot be handled by Java code.

Any ideas how to throw Java exception in JRuby and catch it in Java?

Comment: +1 it seems to me that throwing a Java exception within JRuby and catching it in Java code should be supported.  All I know to do is to catch ScriptExpression, but that doesn't allow testing for specific exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

This is a complete re-write of my original answer as I originally mis-read your question!

You can raise Java exceptions and catch them in JRuby but you need to be a bit careful how you call raise:

```
raise ModelException
```

Will cause a type error (as you saw) because to JRuby `ModelException` looks like a plain constant. Remember that in Ruby class names are constants. You can raise direct subclasses of Ruby `Exception` like this, e.g.:

```
raise RuntimeError
```

But I think such subclasses are a special case. Those that are actually Java classes you need to call with a constructor:

```
raise ModelException.new
```

Or whatever constructor/s you have for that class. An instance of `ModelException`, in JRuby, is a subclass of `Exception` because JRuby creates it as such, but the Java class itself isn't. All this is assuming that you have imported your `ModelException` class correctly.

As for your second example, I couldn't replicate that error at all. As long as I created the exception object correctly, as above, it worked and I didn't see any complaints about "Native Exception" at all. So I'm not sure what is happening there, sorry.